# Appcenter Appium Test - java.io.FileNotFoundException (No such file or directory)

Tags: log4j, appium, azure-automation, visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-test

I'm trying to run my appium test on appcenter.

After uploading test to appcenter and its bout to execute my test i get the error bellow

java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/test/resources/properties/Config.properties (No such file or directory)at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method

Note: I successfully run the test on my local with any issues but on trying to execute on app center i get the above error

```
Something went wrong while running your tests
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building run-test 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ run-test ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ run-test ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ run-test ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ run-test ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.20:test (default-test) @ run-test ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running appiumTest.TestCase.Rough
Logging xtc events to event_stream.log
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (devpinoyLogger).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file [src/test/resources/properties/log4j.properties].
java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/test/resources/properties/log4j.properties (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:372)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:403)
    at appiumTest.base.TestBase.Capabilities(TestBase.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:340)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:294)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:176)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:122)
    at org.testng.TestRunner$$Lambda$45/479397964.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:770)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:591)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:402)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:396)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:355)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:304)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1180)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1102)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1032)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1000)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:135)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeSingleClass(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:112)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:99)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:386)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:323)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:143)
log4j:ERROR Ignoring configuration file [src/test/resources/properties/log4j.properties].
Feb 08, 2020 10:53:57 AM io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1 lambda$0
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
In the cloud
java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/test/resources/properties/Config.properties (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at appiumTest.base.TestBase.setUp(TestBase.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:340)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:294)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:176)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:122)
    at org.testng.TestRunner$$Lambda$45/479397964.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:770)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:591)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:402)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:396)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:355)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:304)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1180)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1102)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1032)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1000)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:135)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeSingleClass(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:112)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:99)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:386)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:323)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:143)
[ERROR] Tests run: 3, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2, Time elapsed: 56.019 s <<< FAILURE! - in appiumTest.TestCase.Rough
[ERROR] setUp(appiumTest.TestCase.Rough)  Time elapsed: 55.821 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException

[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Failures: 
[ERROR]   Rough>TestBase.setUp:98 » NullPointer
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 3, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2
[INFO] 
[ERROR] There are test failures.

Please refer to target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ run-test ---
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
[INFO] Building jar: target/run-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.20:integration-test (default) @ run-test ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent! The file encoding for reports output files should be provided by the POM property ${project.reporting.outputEncoding}.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.20:verify (default) @ run-test ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:07 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-02-08T10:54:00+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/211M
[INFO] ------------------------------
```

My Test Scrip code on eclipse 
[image]

Comment: Are you running your appium tests on appcenter through CLI or appcenter post build script?

Comment: Through CLI using this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/preparing-for-upload/appium

Comment: Its clearly saying java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/test/resources/properties/log4j.properties (No such file or directory)

Comment: Yes, i know and thats the issue i need to resolve on appcenter. 
It runs successfully on my laptop but when i upload to appcenter and run the test its says java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/test/resources/properties/log4j.properties (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 0):

hope the above issue is resolved.
if not then do not provide absolute path of file starts from 'src' folder because we do not give src package to app center for execution. we prepare upload folder and submit this package to app center. please see your upload package and create path.
upload package must have resources/properties/log4j.properties.
for example: try like this
String path =
System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//test-classes//Resources//testdata.xlsx";